# How to remove the change check in hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, hibernate-entitymanager

Hibernate checks the state of entities when committing transactions. This is useless and performance-critical when fetching large amounts of data to send to the client.

I found a solution with

```
 entityManager.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);
```

I put back `auto` after the query.
Are there any normal more compact solutions.

Now I'm thinking of doing something similar to **aspectJ** so I don't clutter up the code and I can annotate both the service and the repository. What do you think about this and how do you solve such a problem?

Example:

```
@Override
public Collection<ZoomCallInfoDTO> findZoomCalls(Collection<ContactId> invitedUsers, String name, Date startTime, Date endTime, int offset, int limit, boolean asc, callId callId)
{
    // Why we did it?
    // Due to bad logic of finding calls in time interval (ZoomCallRepository#findAllByProfileAndcallWithinRange)
    // which loaded all calls for user to compute periodical calls there are TOO many entities in hibernate.
    // So during converting calls to DTOs we also have N x M queries (N - number of call to return, M - number of queries for each call conversion).
    // Each query makes hibernate checks all loaded entities for autoFlush policy. And we have bad performance ((
    // Possible decisions:
    // 1. Switch off autoFlush policy for GET methods:
    //    1.1 - Use readOnly transaction (not good for us now because stating top transaction logic is not managed)
    //    1.2 - Set flushMode manually (not good as persistence decision but the cheapest now) - CURRENTLY USED
    // 2. Decrease number of loaded to hibernate entities - it need to redesign logic of computing periodical calls
    // 3. Merge of 1 and 2 decisions - SHOULD BE IMPLEMENTED IN FUTURE
    entityManager.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);

    if (invitedUsers != null && !invitedUsers.isEmpty())
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Search by invited users is not supported.");
    }

    UserProfile profile = callUtil.getCurrentUserProfile();

    List<ZoomCallInfoDTO> callDTOs = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<callId, callCacheItem> callCache = new HashMap<>();
    for (ZoomCall call : ZoomCallRepository.findAllByProfileAndcallWithinRange(profile.getId(), name, startTime, endTime, offset, limit, asc, callId))
    {
        callDTOs.add(create(call, profile.getId(), callCache));
    }

    entityManager.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.AUTO);

    return callDTOs;
}
```

I noticed that after such operations there is an "autoflush" there are too many of them

Comment: Have you tried `@Transactional(readOnly=true)`, however if you are reading only data the dirty checking shouldn't kick in, unless you are doing multiple queries and thus probably sub-optimal access in the first place.

Comment: @M.Deinum The problem is that I can assemble a complex object. To do this, I can pull data from different repositories and change it. My task is not to make unnecessary checks

Comment: Please add some code, also if you do a lot of queries you are probably doing the wrong thing and should write a dedicated query to retrieve what you want in 1 go instead of reaching out to different repositories, retrieve half the world and ditch 80% of that.

Comment: @M.Deinum Update!

Comment: Fixing `findAllByProfileAndConferenceWithinRange` is not an option?

Comment: @dpr Of course not, hibernate will constantly do dirty checks on the layers above

Comment: @WBLord based on your comments in the code snippet I understood, that the large amount of entities read in `findAllByProfileAndConferenceWithinRange` is the root cause of the problem as this adds way too many entities to hibernate and hibernate takes ages for the dirty checks. Right? If that's correct you could change `findAllByProfileAndConferenceWithinRange` to not fetch managed entities but a custom class that is not managed by hibernate...

Comment: @dpr My task is to have a method that is able to transactionally pull out a large number of entities, while not constantly doing dirty checks. Then transfer these entities to a higher level (there should be one transaction) And there it is already possible to flash entities

Answer (score 4):

One solution is implementing `CustomEntityDirtinessStrategy`

```
properties.setProperty("hibernate.entity_dirtiness_strategy", EntityDirtinessStrategy.class.getName());
```

Details in:

[How to customize Hibernate dirty checking mechanism](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-customize-hibernate-dirty-checking-mechanism/)

More in:

[Options for Entity Dirtness Checking](https://in.relation.to/2013/04/10/options-for-entity-dirtness-checking/)

Comment: These are useful articles, but I need to do it at the service level.

Comment: Not in this case

Answer (score 0):

The CustomEntityDirtinessStrategy is a recent Hibernate API addition, allowing us to provide an application-specific dirty checking mechanism.
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
public class EntityDirtinessStrategy implements CustomEntityDirtinessStrategy {

```
@Override
public boolean canDirtyCheck(Object entity, EntityPersister persister, Session session) {
    return entity instanceof DirtyAware;
}

@Override
public boolean isDirty(Object entity, EntityPersister persister, Session session) {
    return !cast(entity).getDirtyProperties().isEmpty();
}

@Override
public void resetDirty(Object entity, EntityPersister persister, Session session) {
    cast(entity).clearDirtyProperties();
}

@Override
public void findDirty(Object entity, EntityPersister persister, Session session, DirtyCheckContext dirtyCheckContext) {
    final DirtyAware dirtyAware = cast(entity);
    dirtyCheckContext.doDirtyChecking(
        new AttributeChecker() {
            @Override
            public boolean isDirty(AttributeInformation attributeInformation) {
                String propertyName = attributeInformation.getName();
                boolean dirty = dirtyAware.getDirtyProperties().contains( propertyName );
                if (dirty) {
                    LOGGER.info("The {} property is dirty", propertyName);
                }
                return dirty;
            }
        }
    );
}

private DirtyAware cast(Object entity) {
    return DirtyAware.class.cast(entity);
}
```

}